# Find Recursive Definition from given formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

I've read some ways about how to derive a formula from a recursive definition, but what about this one?

I started solving this formula

$$ a_n = 2^n + 5^n n , n \in \mathbb{N} $$

gives you the recursive definition of what and how you go about figuring that out? Any tips for me?

My calculations so far

$$ (r-2)(r-5) = r^2 - 7r + 10 $$

Am i doing right?

Comment: I'm assuming, from your attempt, that you mean $a_n = 2^n + 5^nn$?

Comment: This is not clear.  You have provided a closed form for $a_n$, what else do you want?

Comment: @BrianTung yes i do

Comment: @lulu i am trying to find a recursive definition for that formula

Comment: @lulu: Normally, we are given a recursion, such as $F_n = F_{n-1}+2F_{n-2}$ or some such (along with some initial values), and we attempt to derive a direct formula for $F_n$.  I think OP wants to try to reverse this process.

Comment: @BrianTung that is exactly what i mean. thank you for your help sorry for my bad English is not my native language

Comment: If you are looking for a recursive relation satisfied by those $a_n$, you'll need to look at the cubic $(r-2)(r-5)^2$.  You need that double root at $r=5$ to get the coefficient $n$.

Comment: @BrianTung  Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the coefficient $n$ here, you'll need a double root at $r=5$.  Thus you should look at the characteristic polynomial $$(r-2)(r-5)^2=r^3-12r^2+45r-50$$

It follows that the recursion we want is $$a_n=12a_{n-1}-45a_{n-2}+50a_{n-3}$$ with initial conditions $$a_0=1\quad a_1=7\quad a_2=54$$

Comment: It's clear. Thank you!